# Tkinter: Proper way to withdraw Tkinter root window with multiple instances

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, pmw

I'm using Pmw to create a nice listbox. First, I get a file path via Tkinter file dialog, then do some operating on the data in that location. Then I try to show the listbox.

If I put the root and withdraw before the file dialog line, the listbox will not appear. However, if I move it to after the file dialog request, the listbox will appear, but I can't find a way to get rid of the root window.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyautogui as gui
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
from pathlib import Path
import Pmw

all_file_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
raw_root = tk.Tk()
raw_root.withdraw()

---------------------
# Do some stuff
---------------------

class choiceBox( Frame ):
   def __init__( self, listItems ):
      Frame.__init__( self )
      self.pack( expand = YES, fill = BOTH )
      self.master.title( "Select" )

      self.listBox = Pmw.ScrolledListBox( self,
                                          items = listItems,
                                          listbox_height = 5,
                                          vscrollmode = "static",
                                          listbox_selectmode = EXTENDED )
      self.listBox.pack( side = LEFT, expand = YES, fill = BOTH,padx = 5, pady = 5 )

      self.copyButton = Button( self,text = ">>>", command = self.addThing )
      self.copyButton.pack( side = LEFT, padx = 5, pady = 5 )

      self.chosen = Pmw.ScrolledText( self,text_height = 6,text_width = 20 )
      self.chosen.pack( side = LEFT, expand = YES, fill = BOTH,padx = 5, pady = 5 )

   def addThing( self ):
      self.chosen.clear()
      selected = self.listBox.getcurselection()

      if selected:
         for item in selected:
            self.chosen.insert( END, item + "\n" )

names = ("A", "B", "C", "D")
choiceBox( names ).mainloop()
```

Any explanation here would be greatly appreciatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution;

```
raw_root.update()
raw_root.deiconify()
```

Putting the root and withdraw before the filedialog and then putting the above code before the listbox is generated, fixes the issue.